# How to submit multiple spark jobs to single AWS EMR cluster

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-emr

I am trying to submit multiple jobs to the EMR cluster but I see only the first one in running state and rest all are in Accepted state. The majority of my jobs are streaming Jobs.

I have the following queries:

1. How can I achieve the parallel run of these jobs?
2. What are the various ways to automate these jobs for future deployment?
3. How can I handle scheduled jobs (like a job running once every 15 minutes)?

I am using Java for development. Any inputs will be really helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the multiple steps in the EMR are not dependent on each other, then you can use the feature called `Concurrency` in the EMR to solve your use case. This feature simply means that you can run more than 1 step in parallel at a time.

This feature is there from the EMR version **5.28.0**. If you are using the older version than this then you can not use this feature.

While launching the EMR from the AWS console, this feature is termed as **'Concurrency'** in the UI. you can choose any number between 1 to 256.

If you are launching the EMR from the AWS CLI, then this feature is termed as **'StepConcurrencyLevel'**.

You can read more about this at [multiple steps now in EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/amazon-emr-now-allows-you-to-run-multiple-steps-in-parallel-cancel-running-steps-and-integrate-with-aws-step-functions/)   and [AWS CLI details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/APIReference/API_RunJobFlow.html#EMR-RunJobFlow-request-StepConcurrencyLevel)

To answer your second question about **how can I handle schedule jobs?**

There are multiple ways to do this. One simplistic way which I can think of is to write a **lambda function that spawns this EMR**. Now, this lambda function can be scheduled in  AWS cloudwatch to run at any frequency that you want (say every 15 minutes or any time interval). You just need to mention a **Cron expression** which will decide by which frequency this rule would be triggered.

So every time the rule gets triggered, it will execute your lambda function. And your lambda function in turn would spawn the EMR. In this way you can schedule your jobs.

Comment: Do you mean spawn multiple EMR clusters? Unclear. If so, then Step Concurrency Level is surely better?

Comment: @thebluephantom It depends on the use case, If you want to schedule the Job after a very long time say every 12 hours and your job itself runs in 1 hour, then I would like to schedule this every 12 hours instead of keeping the EMR idle for so long period. But if the scheduling frequency is very less say every 15 minutes, and job completion time also is less, then I would go for the option of adding steps in the already created EMR and use concept of `Step Concurrency`. As far as I understood from the question, he wants to automate it, so suggested the lambda way which will spawn multiple EMR.

Comment: OK, gotcha, but I did mean concurrent. Just checking. Thx.